# Editing the built-in autocorrect dictionary in AOSP keyboard

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard, auto-correct

I'd like to remove some words from the built-in dictionaries<sup>*</sup> in my AOSP keyboard (Cyanogenmod 11), to avoid autocorrect from suggesting/applying them.

Is there a dictionary file that can be edited to remove such words?

I suspect it might require root do be able to change it, but I don't mind if it does.

**Note**: I'm not talking about words added to my personal dictionary, which can be erased using the appropriate interface. I'd like to remove, for instance, the word `Said` from the French dictionary, which often appears when I mistype `sais` (a quite common French word). I never intend to use `Said`, but since it is already in the built-in dictionary, there is no standard way to simply delete it, AFAIK.

<sup>*</sup> Including languages other than English.

Comment: There is a workaround mentioned in this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61214/96277). It doesn't help in editing the dictionary but gets the job done.

Comment: That question seems to be related to user-added words, not the built-in dictionary. I tried with some words and there is no "Replace..." popup, unless the word has been added by myself. In any case, I edited my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

This [other SE answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24548) might be of help if your phone is running under CyanogenMod. That answer, in turn, points to [this article](http://blog.cone.be/2010/08/19/android-keyboard-dictionaries/) where author shows the location of built-in dictionaries on the phone filesystem, as well as the location of built-in dictionary source files in Android open source project.

The rationale (all to be tried) should be grab the source of a builtin dictionary you want to edit, modify that, generate a new APK file out of that, and finally substitute the original dictionary APK with the custom APK.

Comment: Seems like a good start, but how do you generate a new APK from the dictionary source file, and how to you substitute the original with it? Edit: this might be helpful http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1027207