# Bulk add words to the user dictionary in Android 7.1.1 without root

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, languages, dictionary, text-prediction

I'm aware that since Android 6, Google doesn't allow apps to access the user dictionary anymore.

I have a user dictionary of about 500 words, which would be an incredible pain in the back to insert manually, so I'm looking for a viable method.

Previously I had a rooted Android 6, where I copied, modified and replaced the SQLite database on the phone. [See this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24585/194076).

My current phone is not rooted, so I have no access to said database via `adb` or on the phone directly.

Is there no way to bulk add or copy/paste the user dictionary of the phone without rooting it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a (paid) app which let you backup/restore and bulk add words to user dictionary: 
[user dictionary plus app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paolinoalessandro.dictionaryplus&hl=en_IN)